# Is it possible to calculate the strains applied by a force on a molecule?

Tags: materials, pressure, material-science, deformation

This question was originally in the Physics site, but the moderator believed it was better suited for this site. Hence, I am following the advice.

Is it feasible to obtain the modulus of elasticity and Poisson ratio of a single molecule of Fullerene?
As these properties are normally obtained from macroscopic objects, trying to get the properties of a single fullerene molecule is struggling, as a bulk mass of fullerene's (Fullerite) does not represent the intramolecular forces of fullerene but rather the intermolecular forces between fullerene's.
The modulus of elasticity and Poisson ratio that are of focus in this scenario are the one's displayed by the intramolecular forces of a singular molecule.

Comment: It is possible if deformable, and measurable.

Comment: Instead of arguing where it might be answered the best, try to focus on actually answering the question.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to share it to Matter Modelling, but I do not believe a question can be posted twice

Comment: A quote from Quora may interest you - "In their work, the scientists note that diamond hasn’t been the hardest material for some time now. Natural diamonds have a hardness of nearly **150 GPa,** but ultrahard fullerite has surpassed diamond to become first on the list of hardest materials with values that range from **150 to 300 GPa.** https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-Fullerite

Comment: Since it mainly consists of carbon atoms, it is very hard and rigid (not extendable), you should look into the diamond to see how they measure its Young's Modulus, which is around 1050-2000 GPa.

Answer (score 0):

This is my opinion (as an engineer) as  to why the modulus of Elasticity --as it is used by engineers-- cannot be applied in the same manner in this context (at least without significant modification).

### Modulus of Elasticity common engineering definition

The usual definition of the Young's Modulus is:

$$E = \frac{\Delta \sigma}{\Delta \epsilon}$$

where:

- $\Delta\sigma = \frac{\Delta F}{A_0}$ is the stress difference over a region (F is the force and $A_0$ the initial cross-section of the **test specimen**)
- $\epsilon= \frac{\Delta L}{L_0}$ is the strain difference over a region ($L_0$ is the initial length of the **test specimen**)

So the modulus can be calculated as:

$$E =  \frac{\Delta F}{A_0}\frac{\Delta L}{L_0}=  \frac{\Delta F\cdot L_0}{\Delta L\cdot  A_0} $$

This work very well for the typical tensile specimens

[image]

Also, the modulus of elasticity is a **macro-scale** property (at least for engineers).

### application to Fullerene

When you refer to a "molecule of Fullerene", I interpret that as a variation of the C60 allotrope (buckminsterfullerene).
[image]

There are others also in the form of a tube but there is more difficult to visualise the term molecule.

For this type of structure which is round, hollow and also the "connecting rods" are nothing more than visualisations of the bond (there is no actual thickness there), the modulus of elasticity has several difficulties to be applied.

The most obvious one (to me at least) is that when you apply a uniaxial force on a round molecule then the different **connections** (I use that word intensionally) between the molecules don't experience the same force/stress. So, at different points depending on the loading there will be different forces, and therefore different moduli. So one question that arises is what do you use for $\Delta F$.

The big issue is what do you substitute for the cross-section $A_0$ of the connections. This intramolecular connection (between two atoms of Carbon), does not have (in my mind) a measurable size (to my little understanding of a quantum physis its a probabilistic function of where the shared electron will be).

To sum up, to me measuring the modulus of elasticity would not make sense.

### Possible alternative (IMHO)

IMHO, an effective alternative is to try to measure the intramolecular stiffness as a spring constant, i.e.

$$F= K\cdot \Delta x$$

I.e. compress the molecule specimen and then calculate the spring constant for each bond.

This could be possible with optical method. I.e. apply a force and then measure the displacement with some sort of microscope. However even then there are technical difficulties. For example, most scanning electron microscope can go up to 1 nm and the C60 diameter is about 0.7 nm, which makes this not possible (although there are other technologies that might be able to get to the desired resolution).